# Jquery partial append

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, append

I want to add 28 div to my main html element width data and specific css inside. 2 times x 14 div.

I don't understand why this works and show 28 div in my page :

```
createCards: function() {
var cards = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 14 ; i++) {
  var card = $('<div>').addClass('carte cache');

  card.css('background-position', '0 ' + app.backgroundTop + 'px').data('id', i);
  cards[i] = card;

  app.backgroundTop -= 100;
}
app.backgroundTop = 0;
for(var i = 15; i <= 28 ; i++) {
  var card = $('<div>').addClass('carte cache');

  card.css('background-position', '0 ' + app.backgroundTop + 'px').data('id', (i-14));

  cards[i] = card;

  app.backgroundTop -= 100;
} 
$('main').append(cards);
```

and this does not :

```
var cards = [];

for(var i = 1; i <= 14 ; i++) {
  var card = $('<div>').addClass('carte cache');

  card.css('background-position', '0 ' + app.backgroundTop + 'px').data('id', i);
  cards[i] = card;
  cards[i+14] = card;

  app.backgroundTop -= 100;
}
$('main').append(cards);
```

I try this, i also try to add each var card to a spécific array and use concat fonction after but it's always the same result. I only have 14 div on my page while i have 28 élements when i console log the array .. ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

In the second example, you're assigning `cards[i]` and `cards[i+14]` to the same jquery-created div instance. This will register as the same object to jquery, so it will only be added once. You need separate declarations of `$('<div>')` for each index of the array, or use `card.clone()` for the second one if you really want them to be the same.

Think of it as they are the same element, and one element can only be in one place.